# QueryDsl - creating query with subquery operating on two tables

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, querydsl

I'm new with this API and I'm having some problems with a subquery. I'm using `QueryDsl - JPA`. I have two tables e.g. `Film` and `Producer`. In `Producer` table I have a primary key `producer_id` and in my `Film` table I also have this field as `producer_id` and it's connected. My goal is to count number of `film` entity for specific `producer` using `QueryDsl`.

I wrote something like it:

```
QFilm film = QFilm.film;
QProducer producer = QProducer.producer;
createQuery().from(film, producer).select(film.count())
            .where(film.producerId.eq(producer.producerId)).fetch();
```

I'm getting a sum of all matching results, e.g. in `Producer` table I have 2 producers, and in `Film` table I have 4 films. First producer have 2 films, and second also have 2. Result of this query is 4. But I want for this particular query to return only 2 for first producer, and only 2 for second one. How to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning what is the relationship between the two db fields(OneToMany, OneToOne e.t.c). Also you are declaring a `QFilm` and `QProducer` instance without actually using them in the query.

Assuming that there is OneToOne relationship between `producer.producer_id` - `film.producer_id` and you are using the Querydsl's generated metamodel classes I would try this:

```
    QFilm qFilm = QFilm.film;
    long count = creatyQuery().selectFrom(qFilm).where(qFilm.producerId.eq(yourDesiredProducerId)).fetchCount();
```